# how i split this uv maps in the uv maps panel?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

as the title saids, i need to split or separate this uv maps one part in one layout and another in another layout. [image] [image]

Comment: "UV maps always include the whole mesh." https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv_image/uv/layout_management.html If you want to add two different texture for the two part of the mesh, you have to assign two different materials for them. It's make no sense, but if you really want to do it, you can separate the mesh (select, then hit p) then rename one of their UVMap, then join them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution i had to separate the mesh of the uv map that i wanted to separate and then rename the uv map layouts to not get confuse with them and then delete the uv layout of the uv map that i dont want to keep in both meshes and then i re joined the two meshes again and it fortunately works!!!.